# screen: Any "screen" is not defined in pygame zero

Tags: python-3.x, pgzero

I'm coding a simple quiz game with pygame zero and pygame. But somehow the screen is not defined. I'm very new with coding so I mostly rely on stackoverflow. Didn't find anything that answers my question. I'm using the book "Computer Coding Python Games for Kids"

```
import pgzrun
import pygame

WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720

main_box = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 820, 240)
timer_box = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 240, 240)
answer_box1 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 495, 165)
answer_box2 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 495, 165)
answer_box3 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 495, 165)
answer_box4 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 495, 165)

main_box.move_ip(50, 40)
timer_box.move_ip(990, 40)
answer_box1.move_ip(50, 358)
answer_box2.move_ip(735, 358)
answer_box3.move_ip(50, 538)
answer_box4.move_ip(735, 538)

answer_boxes = [answer_box1, answer_box2, answer_box3, answer_box4]

score = 0

time_left = 10

q1 = ["What is the capital of France?",
    "London", "Paris", "Berlin", "Tokyo", 2]

q2 = ["What is 5+7?",
    "12", "10", "14", "8", 1]   

q3 = ["What is the sevent month of the year?",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", 4]

q4 = ["Which is the closest planet to the Sun?",
    "Earth", "Neptune", "Mercury", "Venus", 3]

q5 = ["Where are the pyramids?",
    "India", "Egypt", "Morocco", "Canada", 2]

questions = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5]
question = questions.pop(0)

screen.draw.textbox(str(time_left), timer_box, color = ("black"))
screen.draw.textbox(question[0], main_box, color = ("black"))

index = 1
for box in answer_boxes:
    screen.draw.textbox(question[index], box, color = ("black"))
    index = index + 1

def draw():
    screen.fill("dim grey")
    screen.draw.filled_rect(main_box, "sky blue")
    screen.draw.filled_rect(timer_box, "sky blue")

    for box in answer_boxes:
        screen.draw.filled_rect(box, "orange")

def game_over():
    pass

def correct_answer():
    pass

def on_mouse_down():
    pass

def update_time_left():
    pass

pgzrun.go()
```

the error says:

> NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

Comment: i thought i didnt have to define the screen because i have these WIDTH = blablabla and HEIGHT = blablabla. Can you tell me how to define the screen?

Answer (score 0):

`screen` is not defined before calling `pgzrun.go()`. Only use the [`screen`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#screen) object in `draw`. There's no point in drawing anything outside of `draw` or before `pgzrun.go()`. Move the entire drawing in `draw`:

```py
def draw():
    screen.fill("dim grey")

    screen.draw.filled_rect(main_box, "sky blue")
    screen.draw.filled_rect(timer_box, "sky blue")
    for box in answer_boxes:
        screen.draw.filled_rect(box, "orange")
    
    screen.draw.textbox(str(time_left), timer_box, color = ("black"))
    screen.draw.textbox(question[0], main_box, color = ("black"))
    for index, box in enumerate(answer_boxes):
        screen.draw.textbox(question[index], box, color = ("black"))
```